# Block ESC and Enter keys in modeless dialog box (Win32, non-MFC)

Tags: c++, winapi, modeless-dialog

There're some articles written on this subject, but none of them worked in my case. I'm writing the following using Win32 (no MFC). The goal is to prevent `ESC` or `ENTER` keys from closing the modeless dialog box.

Here's the dialog template:

```
IDD_DIALOG_1 DIALOGEX 0, 0, 345, 179
STYLE DS_SETFONT | DS_FIXEDSYS | WS_MAXIMIZEBOX | WS_POPUP | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU | WS_THICKFRAME
CAPTION ""
FONT 8, "MS Shell Dlg", 400, 0, 0x1
BEGIN
    CONTROL         "New Pt",IDC_CHECK_NEW_PT,"Button",BS_AUTOCHECKBOX | BS_PUSHLIKE | WS_TABSTOP,7,3,39,12
    CONTROL         "Lines",IDC_CHECK_LINES,"Button",BS_AUTOCHECKBOX | BS_PUSHLIKE | WS_TABSTOP,54,3,39,12
    CONTROL         "Curves",IDC_CHECK_CURVES,"Button",BS_AUTOCHECKBOX | BS_PUSHLIKE | WS_TABSTOP,94,3,39,12
    CONTROL         "Ellipses",IDC_CHECK_ELLIPSE,"Button",BS_AUTOCHECKBOX | BS_PUSHLIKE | WS_TABSTOP,134,3,39,12
    CONTROL         "Circles",IDC_CHECK_CIRCLE,"Button",BS_AUTOCHECKBOX | BS_PUSHLIKE | WS_TABSTOP,174,3,39,12
    LTEXT           "Pen Size:",IDC_STATIC,242,7,30,8
    EDITTEXT        IDC_EDIT_PEN_SIZE,275,3,40,14,ES_CENTER | ES_AUTOHSCROLL | ES_NUMBER
    CONTROL         "",IDC_SPIN_PEN_SIZE,"msctls_updown32",UDS_SETBUDDYINT | UDS_ALIGNRIGHT | UDS_AUTOBUDDY | UDS_ARROWKEYS,316,3,11,14
    EDITTEXT        IDC_EDIT_SRC,7,19,331,106,ES_MULTILINE | ES_AUTOVSCROLL | ES_AUTOHSCROLL | ES_WANTRETURN | WS_VSCROLL | WS_HSCROLL
END
```

To trap those two keys, I change the message loop to this:

```
MSG msg;

// Main message loop:
for(int nR;;)
{
    nR = ::GetMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0);
    if(!nR)
    {
        break;
    }
    else if(nR == -1)
    {
        //Error
        ASSERT(NULL);
        break;
    }

    if(ghActiveModelessDlg)
    {
        BOOL bProcessAsDlgMsg = TRUE;

        if(msg.message == WM_KEYDOWN ||
            msg.message == WM_KEYUP)
        {
            //Try to trap ESC & Enter keys
            if(msg.wParam == VK_ESCAPE)
            {
                //Do not process
                bProcessAsDlgMsg = FALSE;
            }
            else if(msg.wParam == VK_RETURN)
                goto lbl_check_enter;
        }
        else if(msg.message == WM_CHAR)
        {
            //Try to trap ESC & Enter key
            if(msg.wParam == 27)
            {
                //ESC - Do not process
                bProcessAsDlgMsg = FALSE;
            }
            else if(msg.wParam == '\r')
            {
lbl_check_enter:
                //See what window is it
                WCHAR buffClass[256];
                if(::GetClassName(msg.hwnd, buffClass, _countof(buffClass)) &&
                    lstrcmpi(buffClass, L"edit") == 0 &&
                    (::GetWindowLongPtr(msg.hwnd, GWL_STYLE) & ES_WANTRETURN))
                {
                    //This is edit ctrl that can handle its own Enter keystroke
                }
                else
                {
                    //Do not process
                    bProcessAsDlgMsg = FALSE;
                }
            }
        }

        if(bProcessAsDlgMsg)
        {
            if(::IsDialogMessage(ghActiveModelessDlg, &msg))
            {
                continue;
            }
        }
    }

    if (!TranslateAccelerator(msg.hwnd, hAccelTable, &msg))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
}
```

And `ghActiveModelessDlg` is set from within `DlgProc` for the modeless dialog as such:

```
INT_PTR CALLBACK DlgProc(HWND hDlg, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(hDlg)
    {
        //...

        case WM_ACTIVATE:
        {
            //Needed to ensure that keyboard shortcuts are properly processed in the message loop
            ghActiveModelessDlg = wParam != WA_INACTIVE ? hDlg : NULL;
        }
        break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This works ... in most cases. Except this one.

Here's the sequence. Put the focus into the multi-line edit box, then hit any letter/number key and then `ESC`:

[image]

It will then close the dialog.

Any idea how can it pass my override code above?

PS. Interesting observations.

1) If I just hit `ESC` first, my code traps it. It's only when I hit some other key and then `ESC` it fails.

2) If I comment out the line that calls `IsDialogMessage` (and a subsequent `continue`) it stops accepting `ESC`. So my guess is that it's not the edit control that does this.

Comment: `goto lbl_check_enter;` -- Please don't do this.  Structure your code so that this is unnecessary (make that code that the label is addressing a function, and just call the function).  You are jumping into the middle of a nested `else`.  The Windows API is hard enough -- introducing spaghetti logic doesn't help matters.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: yeah, good job, buddy. You fixed the problem!

Comment: Not sure how it fixed the problem, but I know that jumping into the middle of `else` or `if` blocks is never a good idea.

Comment: [Other tricks with WM_GETDLGCODE](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20031126-00/?p=41703).

Comment: @PaulSanders: Those keystrokes will not reach `DlgProc`. That's why I was doing it from the message loop.

Comment: @IInspectable: `GETDLGCODE` wouldn't really work that well since in that case I will have to trap it in **all** child windows of my dialog box. Which is possible but is a lot more work than what I'm proposing above. So my question remains -- why is my code above not trapping all `ESC` keystrokes?

Comment: The edit control is a hot mess. [Just because you're a control doesn't mean that you're necessarily inside a dialog box](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20070820-00/?p=25513) *might* be relevant.

Comment: @IInspectable: Oh boy, that's a mess. No wonder I'm getting all kinds of weird results from that `edit` ctrl. Btw, how come you can quote all those old-new-things so quickly :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if we want let close dialog only by clicking close `X` button in system menu (or by `ALT+F4`) and disable close by `ESC` and `ENTER` key - all what we need - call `DestroyWindow` when process `(WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_CLOSE)` and do nothing on `(WM_COMMAND, IDCANCEL, IDOK)`. we not need special message loop or subcluss any controls. and not have buttons with IDOK/ IDCANCEL id in dialog

```
INT_PTR DialogProc(HWND hwndDlg, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{

    switch (uMsg)
    {
    case WM_SYSCOMMAND:
        if ((wParam & 0xfff0) == SC_CLOSE) DestroyWindow(hwndDlg);
        break;
    case WM_COMMAND:
        switch (wParam)
        {
        case MAKEWPARAM(IDOK, BN_CLICKED):
        case MAKEWPARAM(IDCANCEL, BN_CLICKED):
            // ignore this
            break;
        ....
        }
    }
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`IsDialogMessage` translates ESC key into `WM_COMMAND IDCANCEL` and ENTER into `WM_COMMAND IDOK`. To suppress default handling (closing dialog), process them in your dialog procedure:

```
switch (message)
{
case WM_CLOSE:
    // Handle WM_CLOSE here so it wouldn't generate WM_COMMAND IDCANCEL
    // that would be ignored in WM_COMMAND handler.
    DestroyWindow(hDlg);
    return TRUE;
case WM_COMMAND:
    if ( LOWORD(wParam) == IDCANCEL || LOWORD(wParam) == IDOK )
        // Prevent default handling by original dialog procedure.
        return TRUE;
    break;
// other cases...
}
```

Comment: So concerning your first example. How would I tell apart `IDCANCEL` notification that came from pressing `ESC` key vs. user clicking the `X` button in the title bar, or having selected `Close` in the system menu?

Comment: I have forgotten about this case. Handle `WM_CLOSE` before it gets translated into `WM_COMMAND IDCANCEL`. I have added `case WM_CLOSE` handling in the first code snippet.

Comment: The edit control subclass procedure requests all keys, but then doesn't handle some of them, causing the system to respond with the default warning sound.

Comment: really all much more simply. not need any subclass. if we want close dialog only by click on close menu(button) or *ALT+F4* - need call `DestroyWindow` on `(WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_CLOSE)` and do nothing on `(WM_COMMAND, IDCANCEL)`

Comment: Sorry, I can't mark this as an answer. There's a ton of similar proposals to do this kinda thing. Unfortunately though subclassing every single control in a dialog to trap `ESC` is not what I'll recommend anyone to do. Thanks for the effort though. @RbMm is right, there's a much more elegant solution.

Comment: But I added **additionally if you want to use ENTER and TAB for editing in edit control**. It looks that you are confused with this section, so i decided to remove it, maybe you really don't plan to use these keys for editing.

Answer (score 0):

*RbMm has a good solution. So I'll mark it as the answer.*

While waiting for a reply I was able to adjust my original message loop and came up with my own solution. So here it is.

Blocking the `Enter` key is easy. All I needed to do was to define a default button (either in the dialog editor in VS, or by sending the `DM_SETDEFID` message) and it will handle all the `Enter` keystrokes.

The gist for blocking `ESC` keystrokes was not to pass any keyboard messages bearing the `ESC` keystroke to any common controls (or children of the dialog window.) As @IInspectable [quoted in the comments](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20070820-00/?p=25513), some of those common controls are quite old and are not implemented up to spec. Moreover, Microsoft usually doesn't fix old UI bugs and simply calls them *features*.

So I accomplished the fix by the following modification that will re-route (or *reflect*) all such messages to my `DlgProc`, which also has the benefit over RbMm's code in that it also allows me to come up with my own processing for the `ESC` keystrokes.

*Also eliminated `goto` for goto-purists:*

```
MSG msg;

// Main message loop:
for(int nR; nR = ::GetMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0);)
{
    if(nR == -1)
    {
        //Error
        ASSERT(NULL);
        break;
    }

    //Need special processing for modeless dialogs
    if(ghActiveModelessDlg)
    {
        //Try to catch ESC keystrokes
        if(
            ((msg.message == WM_KEYDOWN || msg.message == WM_KEYUP) && msg.wParam == VK_ESCAPE) ||
            (msg.message == WM_CHAR && msg.wParam == 27)
            )
        {
            //Was this message sent to the dialog window?
            if(ghActiveModelessDlg != msg.hwnd)
            {
                //If no, then reflect it to our dialog window
                ::PostMessage(ghActiveModelessDlg, msg.message, msg.wParam, msg.lParam);

                continue;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //Dialog's special message-processing
            if(::IsDialogMessage(ghActiveModelessDlg, &msg))
            {
                continue;
            }
        }
    }

    //Regular processing
    if (!TranslateAccelerator(msg.hwnd, hAccelTable, &msg))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is known as pretranslating message. I would recommend to refactor dialog handling into separate function and use function pointer to activate/deactivate it. It will help when you decide to add more modeless dialogs, for example Find Dialog from Common Dialogs.